# C'est quoi, un book?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglicismes

J'ai reçu un courriel récemment d'un ami français où il utilisait le mot *book* pour parler d'un livre de photos. Une recherche sur internet révèle qu'il n'est pas le seul à l'utiliser. Le Wiktionnaire mentionne le sens « portfolio », sans marque de restriction géographique, ce qui est probablement erroné.

1. Est-ce que ce mot est d'usage très courant en Europe francophone (sauf dans le sens « livre de paris », qui figure dans les dictionnaires)?
2. Depuis quand?
3. Y a-t-il des ouvrages de référence qui le répertorient?
4. Quels en sont les sens possibles?
5. Que peut-on dire quant au registre d'emploi de ce mot?

Comment: Le terme de book est pour moi juste utilisé dans la mode, et plus particulièrement lors des castings... Avant de passer un casting, on prépare soigneusement son "book" qui va être présenté lors de l'entretien. c'est un recueille de photos, soit des précédents "shootings" soit des "shootings" perso lorsque l'on a pas encore d'expériences.

Comment: J'entends ce mot depuis au moins les années 90, à la base presque exclusivement dans le domaine de la mode, et puis par extension dans d'autres milieux, dont celui du graphisme. Il désigne à chaque fois effectivement un portfolio de réalisations passées. Mon architecte m'a demandé si elle pouvait prendre des photos de la maison finie pour son "book" par exemple.

Answer (score 11):

Un **book** est utilisé dans les différents milieux utilisant l'*infographie* ou la *photographie*. Son but est de **représenter les différentes création d'un auteur**.

Il est généralement utilisé pour **promouvoir** son auteur et montrer sa façon d'appréhender le domaine dans lequel il évolue. 
Les exemples de domaine où le **book** est le plus utilisé sont :

- La mode, que ce soit pour les mannequins ou les designer de vêtement
- La photographie
- L'infographie
- La publicité

Le mot est très répandu et sera compréhensible par toutes personnes travaillant dans les milieux cités. Son assimilation dans la langue française reste cependant très nouvelle et c'est certainement internet qui en a démocratisé l'usage. De ce fait, il n'est pas vraiment référencé dans les ouvrages.

Answer (score 6):

Je ne sais pas si c'est "courant" dans l'ensemble de la population, mais je crois que le terme est relativement connu au moins comme un terme de l'industrie de la mode. C'est définitivement européen à première vue. Je ne l'ai jamais entendu ici au Québec, *mais* la mode est loin d'être un domaine qui me soit familier.

En ce qui concerne le "quand", le 2e volume de [*Sœur Marie-Thérèse des Batignolles*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C5%93ur_Marie-Th%C3%A9r%C3%A8se_des_Batignolles) inclut une histoire basée entièrement sur ce mot, donc le terme était en usage assez commun déjà dans les années 80 au minimum.

Comment: J'oeuvre dans le domaine informatique au Québec et m'a été donné par la passer, de travailler dans différents domaines tel que le textile, menuiserie, artistiques, mode et autres et puis, je n'ai moi non plus jamais entendu parler du terme « book ».

Answer (score 2):

Un complément sur les sources. Au [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/book/10190), on présente le *book* (n.m.) comme le *dossier d'un artiste, d'un mannequin*; on ne voit dans le [*portfolio*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/portfolio/62800?q=portfolio#62092) que l'*ensemble d'estampes ou de photographies, à tirage limité, réunies sous emboîtage.*

Le *book* est répertorié à *portfolio* dans le dictionnaire de l'*[Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/portfolio) française* et sur [*FranceTerme*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=book&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) ([*GDT*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=112965) reproduit, avec une nuance<sup>1</sup>), où dans les deux cas on suggère de le proscrire; on répète d'en faire de même avec le *book client* (dossier des produits) et le *book vendeur* (dossier du vendeur). Il s'agit d'anglicismes; on a déjà emprunté le *portfolio* à l'anglais (années 1970, *DHLF*/Rey) et on en a étendu le sens en français de sorte qu'il couvre déjà le besoin sémantique pour le *dossier du professionnel* (ce qui peut ne pas être le cas en anglais<sup>2</sup>). [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/book) le marque aussi comme anglicisme. On peut noter qu'il est à l'origine d'autres [anglicismes](http://academie-francaise.fr/booke-overbooke-surbooke). On a déjà des termes qui couvrent les réalités dont on traite ici avec le *book*; cet anglicisme fait double-emploi en français.

---

<sub>1. La nuance c'est qu'on reproduit la notice de *FranceTerme* mais dans une autre entrée pour [*portfolio*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8869994), on indique que le terme s'applique aux domaines des *arts*, de la *photographie* et récemment en *éducation* mais n'a pas vocation à être étendu à tous les domaines. En lisant leur note, j'en déduis que dans tous les autres cas, on préfère le mot *dossier*.</sub>

<sub>2. Il n'est pas clair sur quel sens du mot [*book*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=book&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) on se baserait pour en arriver à un dossier/portfolio; aucun dictionnaire anglais n'en traite, ni même [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/book) qui lui attribue ce sens dans son article en français. Voir le sens 7 [ici](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=portfolio&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) pour l'idée que portfolio est peut-être inadéquat en anglais.</sub>