# How to translate "portfolio" in French

Tags: choix-de-mot

In regards to a portfolio used in the creative industry with examples of creative work (graphic designs, photography, renders,...). Does this translate to `portefeuille` correctly? Or would `porte-folio` or `portfolio` be more accurate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We usually use *portfolio* as well, or book. There's no real translation for that one (it would be *portefeuille* if it had to be translated, but that's not making any sense to use *portefeuille* to talk about a design portfolio). *Portefeuille* is more commonly used to talk about a wallet.

Comment: Pour le [_book_](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/14320/3177), voir aussi cette Q&A. _Portfolio_ est un emprunt depuis 1970, se trouve sur _FranceTerme_.

Comment: business portfolio is translated in french as "portefeuille d'activités"